# Problems extracting a layer from a deep network

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to reproduce [this deep net for pose estimation](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1787163).  (v. 11.3, MacOS)

I download the VGG network, as specified:

```
vgg19 = NetModel["VGG-19 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"];
vgg19sub = Take[vgg19, {1, 23}];
```

I can pull out the input layer by NetExtract

```
enc = NetExtract[vgg19, "Input"]
```

which (apparently) gives a valid net.

However, when I try the next step,

```
enc = NetReplacePart[enc, "ImageSize" -> {368, 368}]
```

I get the error:  "[image]"

I infer that enc is not read as a valid net.  Or might there be another source of the problem.  Of course I cannot proceed after that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the `Head` of the result from `NetExtract` - it's a `NetEncoder` not a `NetChain`. If you want to replace the "Input" part, then you'll need to do this: `NetReplacePart[vgg19, 
 "Input" -> NetEncoder[...]]` i.e put your new NetEncoder for that ImageSize in place of "Input", or use "Input"->enc where enc is the NetEncoder you extracted but with your modifications.